# For any particular user, how to calculate the number of his/her answers that are accepted?

Tags: support, answers, search, users

We can of course calculate that manually, it will take some time depending on how many answers the particular user has provided.

But can it still be done without manual calculation in lesser time? Are there any such search tricks available?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. You can find them.

Observe `Advanced Search Tips` at the right side while searching:

> [image]

In search box, type `user:{your user id or someone whom you want to know} isaccepted:true` .You can know your user id from your url

> https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/4732/rickross

Your user id is `4732`

`isaccepted` is boolean which you have to set `yes/true/1`, if you want to know a user's answers that have been marked "accepted".

So, in [search section](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/search) (or at right top search bar) you have to type, **`user:4732 isaccepted:true`**.  It will give all answers of you which are marked as accepted.

I have searched it  and 164 answers are marked as accepted.  You can visit [this url](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A4732%20isaccepted%3Atrue).

For more shortcuts, visit [help page](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/searching).

Comment: Wow this is really smart.. How did u learn all these tricks?

Comment: @Rickross i know some of these shortcuts through help center topics and  Meta SE posts.

Comment: @The Destroyer - WOW , Superb functions. Excellent answer. Just seen mine :)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is a related data query on [data.stackexchange](http://data.stackexchange.com/). The query name is

- [Users with highest accept rate of their answers](http://data.stackexchange.com/hinduism/query/1433/users-with-highest-accept-rate-of-their-answers).

This gives the Link to your profile, Number of answers and number of accepted answers.  (This excludes self answers).

There is also another query

- [What is my accepted answer percentage rate](http://data.stackexchange.com/hinduism/query/949/what-is-my-accepted-answer-percentage-rate)

Using this query, you can check your accepted answer percentage.

Comment: Note that SEDE updates interval is a week.

Comment: @Pandya Whoa! that is not very fast. But the current data is updated today. I also thought of adding search function but TheDestroyer added in the post. So, I removed that part and gave SEDE

Comment: Nice find. Keep it Up.:)