# The rate at which I accept answers

Tags: support, users, search, data-explorer, accepted-answer

I'm looking to find the ratio "number of questions from me with accepted answer" divided by "total number of questions from me". This is what I mention as my "answer accept rate" or AAR.

Finding the first number is the goal here because the second one is trivial to find. From my profile one can see that [it is 135](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/4732/rickross?tab=profile).

Comment: Also answers by me with acceptance by the asker.

Comment: @Archit That can be known from the answer here: https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/931

Comment: @Archit UAR is what you need: https://data.stackexchange.com/hinduism/query/1361073/uar-and-aar But this query is for 20k+ users only. Feel free to edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this query: [AAR](https://data.stackexchange.com/hinduism/query/1361011/aar?UserId=4732)

A snapshot of result for your account:

[image]

Comment: But why is it showing AAR to be zero? 92/135 is not equal to 0.

Comment: I tried to get float value, it's always giving an integer. Not sure why. @Rickross

Comment: Okay .. but looks like it is giving the correct results.

Comment: But the number 92 includes Qs which don't have any answer. Is it possible to know how many such Qs are there where there is at least one answer but no accepted answer?

Comment: @Rickross Is it? Yeah that should be possible. Let me check.

Comment: Yes it is so the case. Some of my Qs are not answered as of yet.

Comment: @Rickross the query already showing float value 0.68.. total Q which have answer is coming 100 after adding 'q.answerCount > 0' in the query..and ratio is 0.92..

Comment: @YDS I updated my query. :-)