# This search yields the correct result only when I'm logged in and not when I'm logged out

Tags: support, bug, search

I am talking about [this search](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A4732%20isaccepted%3Atrue) mentioned in [this answer](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/931/4732).

It is supposed to give the number of answers by me (or by any user if the number 4732 is changed accordingly) that are accepted. When I am using the search query as a logged in member it is returning the correct result. Right now I checked and it returned "559 results". But every time when I use it without logging in it shows "500 results".

Is this the way the search is supposed to work? Or is it a bug that needs to be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is on purpose, according to staff member @animuson [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342645/295232):

> Search is heavily rate-limited in various ways for anonymous users for performance reasons. Anonymous users get cut off after 500 results and are also limited to three tags when performing tag searches. I believe there were a couple other minor features that are disabled for anonymous users. The sorting options were also disabled at the time, but I don't know if they are still disabled for anonymous users.
>
> They were implemented many years ago to mitigate a DDOS attack and then never removed.

Other searches, like [searching for questions only](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq) also demonstrate this behaviour.